# react-testing-library query whitespace issue

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, wai-aria

I am facing challanges querying with the reccommended `byRole`.
I used the screen.debug() to confirm that the node I want to query is in DOM.
The `aria-labelledby` value is passed to react component as prop and then set to the underlying button element as attribue value.

```
await screen.findAllByRole('button', { name: /Kärpät/i }); // [node]
await screen.findAllByRole('button', { name: /Syväkankaan Kioski/i }) // Unable to find role="button" and name "Syväkankaan Kioski"
```

I managed to workaround with using findAllByTestId but I would prefer to use the roles and would like to understand what is happening. Somehow the whitespace causes matcher to fail!?

`screen.debug(await screen.findAllByRole('button'));` log output:

```
console.log
    <button
      aria-label="Lopeta seuraaminen"
      aria-labelledby="Kärpät"
      class="follow-keyword-toggle-button follow-keyword-toggle-button--active"
      data-testid="follow-button-1477"
      type="button"
    >
      <i
        class="fas fa-heart"
      />
    </button>


  console.log
    <button
      aria-label="Lopeta seuraaminen"
      aria-labelledby="Syväkankaan Kioski"
      class="follow-keyword-toggle-button follow-keyword-toggle-button--active"
      data-testid="follow-button-111"
      type="button"
    >
      <i
        class="fas fa-heart"
      />
    </button>
```

PS I'm implementing a design so dont judge for using button without a text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are passing the optional "accessible name" parameter to `findAllByRole` but you have to understand [how an accessible name is generated](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) to pass the correct value.

There is a precedence list for where the accessible name comes from.  In your code example, you are specifying **two** accessible names: `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby`. Only one will be used.  `aria-labelledby` has higher precedence than `aria-label` so the `aria-label` will be ignored.  See steps 2B (aria-labelledby) and 2C (aria-label) in the above URL.

Also note that `aria-labelledby` should be the ID or list of IDs of other elements in the DOM. I can't tell from your example:

```
 aria-labelledby="Kärpät"
```

if "Kärpät" is the ID of another element or if "Kärpät" is the actual label (a text literal).  If the latter, then you're not using it correctly.

Similarly with:

```
 aria-labelledby="Syväkankaan Kioski"
```

`aria-labelledby` can be a list of IDs so if you have two DOM elements in your code, one with `id="Syväkankaan"` and one with `id="Kioski"`, then you're using it correctly.  But if you expect "Syväkankaan Kioski" to be the label, then you're not using it correctly.

From the way you're calling `findAllByRole`, it appears you think aria-labelledby is a literal string, which is not correct.

Comment: I was indeed using them incorrectly and also passing string literals not ids. So when I pass an id of an html element to aria-labelledby does this mean that the generated accessible name will be the text content of the referenced element? For example aria-labelledby="follow-item-123" would generate accessible name "Kärpät" if there would be a <div id="follow-item-123">Kärpät</div> in the document?

Comment: Yes, that's correct